# Trying to build neural net for digit recognition in Python. Unable to get theta2 and predictions correct

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am following Andrew's Coursera course on machine learning. I am trying to build a 3 layers neural net for digit recognition in Python (784 input, 25 hidden, 10 output). However, I am unable to get the predictions (of the training data) correct (accuracy < 5% at 100 iter, accuracy not increasing with iteration).

J (the cost function) seems to be going down (see photo 1) and I have done gradient checking (before minimizing) and it seems to match to around 1e-11 (see photo 2).

I have compared the theta1 and theta2 after 100 iterations to my working matlab code (see code snippet 1 for octave and code snippet 2 for python). It seems theta1 is reasonably similar but theta2 is very different -- see code snippet 2. (I know they should differ because of the different optimisation routines. However, firstly, I have place the same initial thetas into both codes. Secondly, my reasoning is that they should start to converge, or at least get close, after 100 iterations)

The only error I see is:

> -c:32: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

when running the sigmoid during the optimising. However, I was told that this is not essential and it is normal to encounter this error during optimising? Furthermore, because it is a sigmoid, anytime the input is large, it will tend towards 1 anyways.

I have also attached my code in snippet 3. I have cut out all the other non-essential bits (like gradient checking) to make it as short as possible.

I would appreciate any help into this as I cannot even find where it is going wrong, let alone fix it. Thank you.

Photos:

[J (cost function) decreasing to 1.8 after 12 iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW7m9.jpg)

[Gradient checking before optimizing, they look very similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ZNv.jpg)

Code snippet:

```html
Initializing Neural Network Parameters ...
initial1
  -0.0100100
  -0.0771400
  -0.1113800
  -0.0230100
   0.0547800
  -0.0505500
  -0.0731200
  -0.0988700
   0.0128000
  -0.0855400
  -0.1002500
  -0.1137200
  -0.0669300
  -0.0999900
   0.0084500
  -0.0363200
  -0.0588600
  -0.0431100
  -0.1133700
  -0.0326300
   0.0282800
   0.0052400
  -0.1134600
  -0.0617700
   0.0267600
initial2
   0.0273700
   0.1026000
  -0.0502100
  -0.0699100
   0.0190600
   0.1004000
   0.0784600
  -0.0075900
  -0.0362100
   0.0286200
Doing fminunc

Training Neural Network... 
Iteration   100 | Cost: 6.219605e-01
theta1
  -0.0099719
  -0.0768462
  -0.1109559
  -0.0229224
   0.0545714
  -0.0503575
  -0.0728415
  -0.0984935
   0.0127513
  -0.0852143
  -0.0998682
  -0.1132869
  -0.0666751
  -0.0996092
   0.0084178
  -0.0361817
  -0.0586359
  -0.0429458
  -0.1129383
  -0.0325057
   0.0281723
   0.0052200
  -0.1130279
  -0.0615348
   0.0266581
theta2
   1.124918
   1.603780
  -1.266390
  -0.848874
   0.037956
  -1.360841
   2.145562
  -1.448657
  -1.262285
  -1.357635
```

```html
theta1_initial
[-0.01001 -0.07714 -0.11138 -0.02301  0.05478 -0.05055 -0.07312 -0.09887
  0.0128  -0.08554 -0.10025 -0.11372 -0.06693 -0.09999  0.00845 -0.03632
 -0.05886 -0.04311 -0.11337 -0.03263  0.02828  0.00524 -0.11346 -0.06177
  0.02676]
theta2_initial
[ 0.02737  0.1026  -0.05021 -0.06991  0.01906  0.1004   0.07846 -0.00759
 -0.03621  0.02862]
Doing fminunc
-c:32: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
theta1
[-0.00997202 -0.07680716 -0.11086841 -0.02292044  0.05455335 -0.05034252
 -0.07280686 -0.09842603  0.01275117 -0.08516515 -0.0997987  -0.11319546
 -0.06664666 -0.09954009  0.00841804 -0.03617494 -0.05861458 -0.04293555
 -0.1128474  -0.0325006   0.02816879  0.00522031 -0.1129369  -0.06151103
  0.02665508]
theta2
[ 0.27954826 -0.08007496 -0.36449273 -0.22988024  0.06849659 -0.47803973
  1.09023041 -0.25570559 -0.24537494 -0.40341995]
```

```
#-----------------BEGIN HEADERS-----------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import csv
import scipy
#-----------------END HEADERS-----------------


#-----------------BEGIN FUNCTION 1-----------------
def randinitialize(L_in, L_out):
    w = np.zeros((L_out, 1 + L_in))
    epsilon_init = 0.12
    w = np.random.rand(L_out, 1 + L_in) * 2 * epsilon_init - epsilon_init

    return w
#-----------------END FUNCTION 1-----------------


#-----------------BEGIN FUNCTION 2-----------------
def sigmoid(lz):
    g = 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-lz))

    return g
#-----------------END FUNCTION 2-----------------


#-----------------BEGIN FUNCTION 3-----------------
def sigmoidgradient(lz):
    g = np.multiply(sigmoid(lz),(1-sigmoid(lz)))

    return g
#-----------------END FUNCTION 3-----------------


#-----------------BEGIN FUNCTION 4-----------------
def nncostfunction(ltheta_ravel, linput_layer_size, lhidden_layer_size, lnum_labels, lx, ly, llambda_reg):
    ltheta1 = np.array(np.reshape(ltheta_ravel[:lhidden_layer_size * (linput_layer_size + 1)], (lhidden_layer_size, (linput_layer_size + 1))))
    ltheta2 = np.array(np.reshape(ltheta_ravel[lhidden_layer_size * (linput_layer_size + 1):], (lnum_labels, (lhidden_layer_size + 1))))
    ltheta1_grad = np.zeros((np.shape(ltheta1)))
    ltheta2_grad = np.zeros((np.shape(ltheta2)))
    y_matrix = []
    lm = np.shape(lx)[0]

    eye_matrix = np.eye(lnum_labels)
    for i in range(len(ly)):
        y_matrix.append(eye_matrix[int(ly[i])-1,:]) #The minus one as python is zero based
    y_matrix = np.array(y_matrix)

    a1 = np.hstack((np.ones((lm,1)), lx)).astype(float)
    z2 = sigmoid(ltheta1.dot(a1.T))
    a2 = (np.concatenate((np.ones((np.shape(z2)[1], 1)), z2.T), axis=1)).astype(float)
    a3 = sigmoid(ltheta2.dot(a2.T))
    h = a3

    J_unreg = 0
    J = 0
    J_unreg = (1/float(lm))*np.sum(\
    -np.multiply(y_matrix,np.log(h.T))\
    -np.multiply((1-y_matrix),np.log(1-h.T))\
    ,axis=None)

    J = J_unreg + (llambda_reg/(2*float(lm)))*\
    (np.sum(\
    np.multiply(ltheta1[:,1:],ltheta1[:,1:])\
    ,axis=None)+np.sum(\
    np.multiply(ltheta2[:,1:],ltheta2[:,1:])\
    ,axis=None))

    delta3 = a3.T - y_matrix
    delta2 = np.multiply((delta3.dot(ltheta2[:,1:])), (sigmoidgradient(ltheta1.dot(a1.T))).T)
    cdelta2 = ((a2.T).dot(delta3)).T
    cdelta1 = ((a1.T).dot(delta2)).T

    ltheta1_grad = (1/float(lm))*cdelta1
    ltheta2_grad = (1/float(lm))*cdelta2

    theta1_hold = ltheta1
    theta2_hold = ltheta2
    theta1_hold[:,0] = 0;
    theta2_hold[:,0] = 0;
    ltheta1_grad = ltheta1_grad + (llambda_reg/float(lm))*theta1_hold;
    ltheta2_grad = ltheta2_grad + (llambda_reg/float(lm))*theta2_hold;
    thetagrad_ravel = np.concatenate((np.ravel(ltheta1_grad), np.ravel(ltheta2_grad)))

    return (J, thetagrad_ravel) 
#-----------------END FUNCTION 4-----------------


#-----------------BEGIN FUNCTION 5-----------------
def predict(ltheta1, ltheta2, x):
    m, n = np.shape(x)
    p = np.zeros(m)

    h1 = sigmoid((np.hstack((np.ones((m,1)),x.astype(float)))).dot(ltheta1.T))
    h2 = sigmoid((np.hstack((np.ones((m,1)),h1))).dot(ltheta2.T))
    for i in range(0,np.shape(h2)[0]):
        p[i] = np.argmax(h2[i,:])

    return p
#-----------------END FUNCTION 5-----------------

## Setup the parameters you will use for this exercise
input_layer_size  = 784;  # 28x28 Input Images of Digits
hidden_layer_size = 25;   # 25 hidden units
num_labels = 10;          # 10 labels, from 0 to 9
data = []

#Reading in data, split into X and y, rewrite label 0 to 10 (for easy comparison to course)
with open('train.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)  # rewind
    data_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    if has_header:
        next(data_csv)
    for row in data_csv:
        data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)
x = data[:,1:]
y = data[:,0]
y = y.astype(int)
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] == 0:
        y[i] = 10

#Set basic parameters
m, n = np.shape(x)
lambda_reg = 1.0

#Randomly initalize weights for Theta_initial
#theta1_initial = np.genfromtxt('tt1.csv', delimiter=',')
#theta2_initial = np.genfromtxt('tt2.csv', delimiter=',')
theta1_initial = randinitialize(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size);
theta2_initial = randinitialize(hidden_layer_size, num_labels);
theta_initial_ravel = np.concatenate((np.ravel(theta1_initial), np.ravel(theta2_initial)))

#Doing optimize
fmin = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=nncostfunction, x0=theta_initial_ravel, args=(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, x, y, lambda_reg), method='L-BFGS-B', jac=True, options={'maxiter': 10, 'disp': True})
fmin
theta1 = np.array(np.reshape(fmin.x[:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)], (hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1))))
theta2 = np.array(np.reshape(fmin.x[hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1):], (num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1))))

p = predict(theta1, theta2, x);
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] == 10:
        y[i] = 0

correct = [1 if a == b else 0 for (a, b) in zip(p,y)]  
accuracy = (sum(map(int, correct)) / float(len(correct)))  
print 'accuracy = {0}%'.format(accuracy * 100)
```

Comment: IMHO scikit-learn library would make your live easier. I doubt anyone here would be able (and witting) to answer your question.

Comment: Wasn't Andrew's NG course's code written in Octave/Matlab? Yours is python! Did they change the language?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Yes, it was in Octave. I just wanted to do it once in python.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik Thanks! Scikit is much easier than manually doing the matrices!

Comment: You can np.clip the -lz in the sigmoid to avoid the overflows.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed the problem: it seems I messed up the index

should be:

> y_matrix.append(eye_matrix[int(ly[i]),:])

instead of:

> y_matrix.append(eye_matrix[int(ly[i])-1,:])